# Is there a way to respect field selection in AppSync when caching?

Tags: caching, aws-appsync

I have an AppSync with caching enabled for a lambda data source.
When I'm sending following query:

```
{
  todoItems {
    field1 
  }
}
```

Then I'm getting response for requested field, and this response is also gets cached by AppSync

```
{
  "todoItems":
  [
    { 
      "field1": "some data"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then immediately (while cached item is still there) I'm sending same query but with extra field:

```
{
  todoItems {
    field1
    field2 
  }
}
```

And getting response where this extraField comes with null value:

```
{
  "todoItems":
  [
    { 
      "field1": "some data"
      "field2": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I'm waiting while the cache will expire and sending query once again, and only then getting correct result:

```
{
  "todoItems":
  [
    { 
      "field1": "some data"
      "field2": "other data"
    }
  ]
}
```

So it looks like AppSync cached first response and responding with cached data, even for requests with different selection of subfields.